# access public var of an instance from a different object in actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, class, variables, instance

how do you access property from one class instance to another, assuming both **MCButtonA** and **MCButtonB** instances are defined in the *main* class. This is without using `static` `var`.

I keep on getting:

> 1120: Access of undefined property varA

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class MCButtonA extends MovieClip {
        public var varA:String = "abc";
        public function MCButtonA() {
           // constructor code
        }
    }
}

package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class MCButtonB extends MovieClip {
        public var varB:String = "abc";
        public function MCButtonB() {
           // constructor code
           trace( ?????varA)
        }
    }
}
```

**Main class:**

```
var aButton:MCButtonA = new MCButtonA();
var bButton:MCButtonB = new MCButtonB();
```

Answer (score 0):

`trace(this.parent.aButton.varA);`
**upd**
will work only after both buttons are added to stage

Comment: Wouldn't work, as the trace is in the constructor. There's no `parent` yet to reference.